# how to install Virtualenv when Network is unreachable 

Tags: python, virtualenv

i use this to download Virtualenv : `sudo easy_install virtualenv`

but it show error :

```
Download error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
```

so how to install Virtualenv  when this error ,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ask [someone to download](http://b.pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.5.1.tar.gz#md5=3daa1f449d5d2ee03099484cecb1c2b7) (Download Link) and give a copy to you via any physical medium which can carry and preserve bytes. But as with many things with easy_install process, a good network connection is essential in order for the package to resolve it's dependencies.

If the pypi site is down, as it looks at the moment, consider using it's mirror http://b.pypi.python.org

Answer (score 0):

Get the archive some other way and install like this:

```
tar xf virtualenv-1.5.1.tar.gz
cd virtualenv-1.5.1
sudo python setup.py install
```